# Помогите доработать код jquery

Tags: jquery

Есть вот такой вот проблема https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/118529/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#accordeon .acc-head').on('click', f_acc);
});

function f_acc(){
  $('#accordeon .acc-body').not($(this).next()).slideUp(1000);
    $(this).next().slideToggle(200);
    $(this).find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-bars fa-times');
}
```

Если открываю первый список или закрываю, все работает как надо: плюс заменяется минусом, но если открою следующую, минус так и останется минусом. Как исправить? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function f_acc(){
  $('#accordeon .acc-body').not($(this).next()).slideUp(1000);
  $(this).next().slideToggle(200);

  $('#accordeon .acc-head').not(this).find('.fa').removeClass('fa-bars fa-times');
  $(this).find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-bars fa-times');
}
```